# WSO2 AM - Publish API - Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to publish an API in WSO2 API Manager and when I try to Publish it shows an error:

```
cup-api-manager | Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Failed to parse entry: Null
 password in user information not allowed. between indicies 7 and 5 
cup-api-manager | amqp://admin@wso2.com:***@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://172.28.0.5:5672'
cup-api-manager |        ^^^^^ due to : Null password in user information not allowed. at index
 7: amqp://admin@wso2.com:***@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://172.28.0.5:5672'
```

I've changed my deployment.toml to use an email as user and also a user from LDAP:

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin@wso2.com"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap"
connection_url = "ldap://openldap:389"
....

[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true
```

I'm using a docker-compose with all the services and IS as Key Manager.
wso2is:5.10.0-alpine 
wso2am:3.2.0-alpine

Comment: Have you configured JMS connection url in the deployment.toml? If so, have followed the steps in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#setup-an-e-mail-login? `@` is considered as a special character in this case and should be replaced with `!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RrR said I needed to put the throttling configuration in deployment.toml:

```
[apim.throttling]
enable_data_publishing = false
enable_decision_connection = false
receiver_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"

[apim.throttling.policy_deploy]
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"

[apim.throttling.jms]
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
```